# How to send mail with our domain without being identified as spam?

Tags: node.js, smtp, reset-password, email-confirmation, haraka

I am a nodejs developer and I am searching the best way to send email to users (for verifying emails and resetting passwords) with my domaine name and without being identified as spam
how do big companies like facebook do?
is Haraka recommended for my case?

Comment: Some factors would be encrypted emails, your domain(if it's free, not using https, etc.). I believe some mail servers also score domains sending to them, your domain could be on the low end since it's unknown to them.

Answer (score 1):

Sending emails properly is a complex thing to issue.

Some things to consider :

- Having a dedicated IP to send all your emails from (this can be useful to forge a clean reputation of your sending server) - Also, ensure that your server's IP still clean of any blacklisting (see https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx)
- Set up a [Sender Policy Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208) (SPF)
- Using an authentication protocol with cryptographic signatures like [DKIM](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376)
- Enforcing the security of the two action above with [DMARC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489)
- Properly set-up your DNS records (MX records matching sending addresses, TXT records matching authentication protocols, ...)
- Monitor continuously your outbounds emails for bounces rates and act accordingly to limit your spam ratings

If your application depends heavily on sending emails, it could be wise to refer to third party transactional email services that are dedicated to get the best delivery rates and take care of all those issues properly and focus on your developer needs.